# Is there a way to merge efficiently backward and forward optical flow?

Tags: video, merge, forward, opticalflow

I would like to find dense trajectories for a video

I already have computed backward and forward optical flow and i would like an efficient way on how i could merge them so i can get the necessary information from both of them and get the final trajectories